# Replicate Printed Form With Web Form

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, webforms, screenshot

I'm hoping people have some ideas to help solve this problem.

I am developing a C# ASP.NET website and the client requires an online form that users will fill in and submit. OK, so far so good.....

Imagine, say, a form that you fill in on paper - they normally have a distinctive look specific to the company and will be filed, quite possibly as a legally binding document.

I need to have an online form that when submitted emails the client with something they can print out and will look exactly like their printed forms.

As this is web based, I think the option of capturing a screenshot are out the question, so I'm wondering how best to approach this?

Even if I just had a form that captures the data presented how I want, how could I translate this data into the view they want?

Any ideas and suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to take the raw data that was submitted and import it into a standard document (likely PDF).  You can use Crystal or another reporting solution, or direct to PDF using one of the many PDF .NET solutions that are out there.

I don't think you'd even want to deal with making the document physically match the screen - much easier to make the web look like the web, and make the printed doc look like a printed doc.

Comment: Looks as if I'll just have the form as a normal form and use PDFSharp to build up the document behind the scenes - will be a lot of faffing, but should work hopefully! Thanks.

Comment: Try iTextSharp which is still open source.

Answer (score 1):

Print a page (this one) from a Browser, notice all the headers and footers?

If you want serious control over how it is going to look, you will need to generate a PDF (or maybe XPS).

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use a sepparate page with a CSS that gives the desired look & feel?

Comment: I need to be able to print off a filled in form if that was the case. Not sure that's possible given that it's web-based and I've no control over browsers, resolutions etc.